# When I should hide a toolbar in an Android App?

Tags: navigation, android, material-design, toolbar

I'm designing an app navigation flow. It has a login screen from which we can go to a "Forgot password" screen. Once we logged in we go to the "Main screen" there I've a toolbar with a gear item that goes to the "Profile screen". I was wondering, when should I show a toolbar? should I show a toolbar even when there's no items?. For example in the "Profile screen" I've a toolbar but the only thing that It displays is the back arrow and the screen title. Isn't a waste showing a toolbar there? Is there some reference about this in the Material Design documentation?.

I've been searching through the documentation but I couldn't find any answer that explains when we should show a toolbar and when not.

**UPDATE**

In the main screen I've two tab children, one of the tabs displays a feed list, the other tab displays a list of items (work tool items, crowbars, shovels, helmets, ropes, etc.) to buy. In the main screen toolbar you've a gear icon in the top right corner, there you can go to the profile screen. In the profile screen we've some information about the user, and that's all, just name, username, and a picture.

**UPDATE**

Also keep in mind that I'm talking about Android Material Design.

Comment: can you explain in some more detail that what kind of application you talked about and what will be as items? if possible then explain with some figure

Comment: @JasminJavia See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding,you having confusion with the toolbar. I think when we are displaying the profile info at that time there should be only one back icon in the screen because if you toolbar contains different menu from the profile then there is no need to display toolbar in profile screen. Below is the figure in which I tried to explain you this concept.

[image]

If list is empty in main page then also toolbar will be there so you can just put small message on the screen. by clicking on the menu icon in screen 1 you can display your menu in which "my profile" section will be there. so "my profile" will redirect you to the screen 2.

Hope you understand what I tried to explain you.

Comment: Yeah, but in android we have the back button also.

Comment: So, why are we going to have the toolbar? there's some justification in some material design document?

Comment: Yes you are right @4gus71n that in Android we have back button also but if you keep back icon on the top left then its not out of material design because I have seen many Android apps which have back icon though there is back button facility in Android and out of those apps one of is our StackExchange app also! So you can definitely go through this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really getting any benefit on removing the app bar? Remember that by removing it, the user is losing consistency on the navigation which may lead to some confusion.

Even though on Android devices we have the back button, the programmer will still need to take that in consideration so the device's back button takes the user to the previous view instead of exiting the app.

Comment: You've a good point about that of the navigation consistency, but what I want is see that write down in some official Android Material Design doc.